# different color for data and time in git log output

Tags: git

I am trying to show different color for date and time in the `git log` output.

Currently i am using `git config --global alias.l 'log --pretty=format:"%C(#d33682)%h %C(#b58900)%cd %C(#6c71c4)%ce %C(#2aa198)%s %C(#cb4b16)" --date=format:"%d-%m-%Y %I-%M-%S"'`

So, i tried `git config --global alias.l 'log --pretty=format:"%C(#d33682)%h %cd %C(#6c71c4)%ce %C(#2aa198)%s %C(#cb4b16)" --date=format:"%C(#b58900)%d-%m-%Y %C(#859900)%I-%M-%S"'`

Color inside `--date=format:` is not working for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have two options. First one is using `%cs` which return commit date in format `%Y-%m-%d` and formats time according to format passed in `--date`:

```sh
git log --pretty=format:"%C(#d33682)%h %Cred%cs %C(#b58900)%cd %C(#6c71c4)%ce %C(#2aa198)%s %C(#cb4b16)" --date=format:"%I-%M-%S"
```

Another option wound be to truncate output twice, one time from right, another from left. This one would add those `..` indicating that the column was truncated…

```sh
git log --pretty=format:"%C(#d33682)%h %Cred%<(12,trunc)%cd %C(#b58900)%<(10,ltrunc)%cd %C(#6c71c4)%ce %C(#2aa198)%s %C(#cb4b16)" --date=format:"%d-%m-%Y %I-%M-%S"
```

Other option, in which you could use any datetime format you wish is to left handling colors for other tool ;)

```sh
git log --pretty=format:"%h %cd %ce %s" --date=format:"%d-%m-%Y %I-%M-%S" | awk '{printf "\033[1;31m" $1 "\033[0m \033[1;32m" $2 "\033[0m \033[1;33m" $3 "\033[0m \033[1;34m" $4 "\033[0m \033[1;35m"; $1=$2=$3=$4=""; print substr($0,5)}'
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove the `.. ..` in the second one.

Comment: @blueray I'm not aware of any when it comes to pure `git`, but that question helped me to come with 3rd solution which returns date/time in desired format.

Comment: I think there is an error in the 3rd solution. It is returning zsh: parse error near `}'

Comment: There was a typo: `'}`, instead of `}'`. Strangely enough the version with the typo also worked in bash ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, the third solution is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

OP Here. Thanks to [@bk2204](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64408423/1772898), there is another solution.

Run the following command in the terminal once.

```
git config --global alias.l '!f() {
    git log --format="%ct" | (
    n=0;
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
        date=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y" -d @$line)
        time=$(date +"%H:%M" -d @$line)
        git --no-pager log -1 --skip=$n --decorate\
            --pretty=format:"%C(#d33682)%h %C(#859900)$date %C(#b58900)$time %C(#6c71c4)%ce %C(#2aa198)%s%C(#d30102)%d%n"
        n=$((n + 1))
    done)
}; f'
```

Now every time you use the command `git l`, you will get log according to the requirement of this question.